# KeyCloak Authorization permissions are not being applied

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak

I'm trying to set up a single sign-on in two Java web applications using KeyCloak.

I created a `Realm`, `Client` and `User Federation` (ldap) and configured the two URL applications in the `Client` (Valid Redirect URIs)

After logging in, I can navigate normally through both applications.

After enabling `Authorization Enabled`, I change `Enforcement Policy` as `Enforcing`, which should block access to the pages of the two applications, but access to all pages is still allowed.

I tried to create a `Policy/Resource/Permission group` to block access to certain pages per user or by URL, but it has no effect.

For these permission settings to take effect do I need to do something else?

Comment: keycloak.json


{
  "realm": "myrealm",
  "auth-server-url": "${myrealm.keycloak.url}",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "myresourceid",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "75673358-bfaa-4088-bd95-2a0205cfe966"
  },
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true
}

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply an enforcer to your server applications which will enforce your permissions. I use the nodejs adapter, so in my case I use keycloak's enforcer method 'keycloak.enforcer('resource:scope')' as a middleware to ensure policy/resource/permission is being applied to that API before allowing the user to proceed.

Comment: What kind of client do you use? I try with a `bearer-only`, but the enforcer always returns `403` status code.

Comment: I use a confidential client which requires a secret key. I find it really helpful to go into debugging mode with key-cloak and step through the auth logic.